# feature selection for regression vs classification

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, classification, regression, feature-selection

New to Machine learning so please bear with me, thanks!
I have three questions to ask, so it would helpful if you mention the question number while answering.

so I want to perform feature selection for my training data before i apply the machine learning algorithm. I will use the same data set to run on many different ML algorithms to decide what is best so it will be more efficient if i can just do feature selection once and pass the new data set to the various algorithms.
Note : I am coding in Python3 and I'm going to use BorutaPy for my feature selection. [https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/boruta_py]

Question 1)
do i need to know what algorithm i'm using before performing feature selection? or can i just perform my feature selection and then use whatever algorithm ,ie; is feature selection dependent on the type of algorithm used?

Question 2)
can i perform the same feature selection for regression and classification problems?

Question 3)
Instead of everything mentioned above, is it best to use regularization for the regression problems and perform feature selection for the classification problems?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will respond to your questions 1 & 2, leaving number 3 for someone else. I will use R to make some examples. I know that you are using python, but the answers to your questions do not depend on the implementation. I hope that you can translate them to python or just look at the math and see what is happening.

#### Question 1: Feature selection is dependent on the algorithm used.

First, some data.

```
set.seed(1234)
y  = runif(1000)
x1 = (1-y)^(1/6)
x2 = y + rnorm(1000, 0, 0.1)
```

Here, y is exactly 1 - x1⁶ and y=x2 with some noise added.  Here is a plot to help see that.

[image: y with x1 and x2 as predictors]

We want to predict y from x1 or x2. Which one is better?  First let's use a linear model.

```
LM1 = lm(y ~ x1)
LM2 = lm(y ~ x2)
summary(LM1)$r.squared
[1] 0.8454181
summary(LM2)$r.squared
[1] 0.9022076
```

The model using x2 to predict y has a better R², so x2 is better than x1.

Now let's use kNN regression (with k=1).

```
library(FNN)
NN1 = knn.reg(train=x1, y=y)
NN1$R2Pred
[1] 0.9999928
NN2 = knn.reg(train=x2, y=y)
NN2$R2Pred
[1] 0.8728359
```

The model using x1 has a much better R², nearly perfect. *The best variable depends on the algorithm.*

#### Question 2: Different features may be required for regression and classification.

This is much simpler. If you are doing regression, you are predicting a numerical quantity. If you are doing classification,  you are predicting a categorical variable - so any comparison here will be about predicting different y-values.  Of course, it is possible to make x1 related to y1 but not y2 and x2 related to y2 but not y1.

A simple example is:

```
x1 = runif(1000)
x2 = runif(1000)
y1 = x1
y2 = ifelse(x2<0.5, 1, 2)
```

y1 is equal to x1 so x1 is a perfect predictor of y1. But x2 is random with no relationship to y1 and so a rather poor predictor of y1.   By contrast, y2 is 1 if x2<0.5 and 2 otherwise. x2 is a perfect predictor of y2. But x1 is random with no relationship to y2 and therefore a poor predictor of y2.

More generally, the best predictors will obviously depend on what you are trying to predict. If you are predicting two different variables, there is no reason to think that the same collection of predictors should be best for both.

I hope that this helps.

Comment: Thanks! @G5W your answer has answered my questions 1 and 2 clearly!